# Add a component into Jframe or JLabel created by Netbeans

Tags: java, swing

I'm using Netbeans.

I use Netbeans to create a Jframe and drag and drop a JLabel to Jframe.

I want to add a JLinkButton (I use zfqjava JLinkbutoon) to Jframe and to JLable by using code(but not drap and drop) but it doesn't work.

Here is my code to add JLinkButton to JFrame

```
 this.getContentPane().add(linkButton);
```

and here is my code to add JLinkButton to JLabel

```
 lblbackground.add(linkButton);
```

Comment: So how exactly does "can't do that" manifest? Does the computer blink a big red light at you and say in a warm yet creepy voice "I'm sorry, Chan. I'm afraid I can't do that"?

Comment: 'drop and drap' should be drag and drop :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the same JLinkButton both places.  It will only appear in the last place you add it.  Instead create to instances of it, one for each place you want to put it.